# Should I have an EXE, XPAP, or some other technology to probe my helpdesk's customers' environment?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, xbap

My helpdesk supports  both on-domain and off domain computers for a custom application.

I want to run (and update) an application that customers can use to

1. Diagnose the environment
2. Check network settings
3. Submit helpdesk tickets

What Windows-based (or cross platform technology) should I use to do this?  I am less concerned about UX, but more about the content and the ability to "shell out" and do stuff in their network.

Assume in this case that the customer fully trusts me.

Answer (score 0):

I will throw in an answer before this gets closed.

I've used [GoToAssist](https://www.gotoassist.com/remote-support/remote-support) by Citrix. It gives you remote access to the client system, works over a normal https channel, and gives you the ability to run a diagnostic report on the target system.

Comment: I second this. Our company uses this as well and makes our IT departments lives easier.